# How to run the localhost server for Dart Web Services (error finding local web service)

Tags: web-services, web-applications, localhost, dart

I'm following the dart web service tutorial here:
http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

When I try to run the code from the associated git code https://github.com/chrisbu/dartlang_json_webservice_article_code

I get the following error.

```
Loading structured data
Failed to load resource
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/programming-languages
Uncaught Error: Instance of 'HttpRequestProgressEvent'
Exception: Instance of 'HttpRequestProgressEvent'
```

From the readme https://github.com/chrisbu/dartlang_json_webservice_article_code/blob/master/README.md

it suggests that I need to

```
To execute, either run:

dart simpleserver.dart
Load the project into the Dart Editor, and click "Run"

This starts the server listening on http://localhost:8080
```

Where do I need to run the

> dart simpleserver.dart

command? Is there any other local server setup requirements that I could be missing? Thanks, (Windows 8 Pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your error message if I run the client in a browser without starting the server first.  As noted in the documentation you included (but didn't seem to understand), you have two ways to run the server: from the command line or from Dart Editor.  If you're using Dart Editor:

1. Load `simpleserver/simpleserver.dart` in Dart Editor, then click the 'Run' button.
2. Load `json_clien/web/json_client.dart` in Dart Editor, then click the 'Run' button.

That will load `json_client.html` in the bundled Dartium browser and everything should work.

If you prefer to use the command line (which it sounds like you *don't*), navigate to the `simpleserver` directory, then run `dart simpleserver.dart`.  Then manually load `json_clien/web/json_client.html` in Dartium.

Both ways work for me with Dart 0.5.13.1_r23552 on Linux.